# What are the Words of Power needed to enter the dungeons in Ultima 5?

Tags: ultima-5

What are the Words of Power for each dungeon in order to be able to enter the dungeons?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Virtue          Mantra     Word of Power        Dungeon
===========================================================================
Honesty         Ahm        Fallax               Deceit
Valor           Ra         Vilis                Destard
Compassion      Mu         Inopia               Despise
Honor           Summ       Malum                Shame
Sacrifice       Cah        Avidus               Covetous
Justice         Beh        Infama               Wrong
Spirituality    Om         Ignavus              Hythloth
Humility        Lum        Veramocor            Doom
```

Taken from [this page](http://www.gamefaqs.com/pc/562661-ultima-v-warriors-of-destiny/faqs/8148).